# migrate from C#.net 2.0 to php so the hash value of the password - how to resolve?

Tags: c#, php, hash, migrate, hmac

we previously use a C#.net 2.0 to create a web app.

Users password were hashed and stored in database using the following code.

```
private const string encryptionKey = "AE09F72B007CAAB5";

HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
hash.Key = HexToByte(encryptionKey);
encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(
    hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
```

now we intend to migrate to php.

so we face a problem for users when they want to back in.

what php equivalent of the method should be used so that the hash values in the database would work?

eg password to encode is pa55w0rd 
the hash value gotten is oK9NOVhpTkxLoLfvh1430SFb5gw=

Thank you.

Comment: I am wondering what the reasons are behind a migration from C# to php.  This comment is slightly off topic but I want to understand some reasons behind it.

Comment: we started off with C# because the main developers are more familiar. however, linux hosting is cheaper hence the move to php. that is all. i can understand that we didnt start off with the right decision, but we are committed to getting it right. hence the move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C# app you generate the byte[] arrays in two different ways with a little bit different results. Your PHP script needs to emulate them exactly.

> hash.Key = HexToByte(encryptionKey)

You pass in a 16 characters long string and get an array of 8 bytes, just like `hash.Key = new byte[]{0xAE, 0x09, 0xF7, 0x2B, 0x00, 0x7C, 0xAA, 0xB5 };` but

```
string password = "pa55w0rd";
byte[] b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)
```

returns an array with 16 elements because of the Encoding.Unicode, like `byte[] b = { 0x112, 0x0, 0x97, 0x0, 0x53, 0x0, 0x53, 0x0, 0x119, 0x0, 0x48, 0x0, 0x114, 0x0,0x100, 0x0 }`
In your php script you can change the encoding of $password to utf-16le with [$data = mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF16-LE')](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) to achieve a similar result. hash_hmac() being unaware of any encoding will treat the string a 16 byte single-byte encoded string, just like hash.ComputeHash(byte[]) in .net does.

```
<?php
$password = "pa55w0rd";
$key = HexToBytes("AE09F72B007CAAB5"); // 8 bytes, hex
```

// $to must be 'UTF-16LE'
// $from depends on the "source" of $password
$data = mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF-16LE', 'ASCII');

// I've saved this script as an ascii file -> the string literal is ASCII encoded
// therefore php's strlen() returns 8 for $password and 16 for $data
// this may differ in your case, e.g. if the contents of $password comes from a
// http-request where the data is utf-8 encoded. Adjust the $from parameter for
// mb_convert_encoding() accordingly
echo 'Debug: |data|=', strlen($data), ' |password|=', strlen($password), "\n";

$h = HexToBytes(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $key));
echo 'hmac-sha1: ', base64_encode($h);

function HexToBytes($s) {
  // there has to be a more elegant way...
  return join('', array_map('chr', array_map('hexdec', str_split($s, 2))));
}prints

```
Debug: |data|=16 |password|=8
hmac-sha1: oK9NOVhpTkxLoLfvh1430SFb5gw=
```

Comment: this works! thanks.

i could have just left it like this. but i want to learn and get better at this. so help me with a few questions.

// http-request where the data is utf-8 encoded. Adjust the $from parameter for
// mb_convert_encoding() accordingly

the intention is to build a php login page, so i suppose it will be http request? 
how to tell if it is utf-8 encoding? 
how to adjust the encoding if at all possible?

thank you once again!!

Comment: by the way, i do know that for utf8 i need to change to $data = mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); 

what i meant was the http request.

Comment: In a nutshell: If you send the html doc containing the login form utf-8 encoded you can expect the client to send the login data utf-8 encoded as well. Curious, I couldn't find a question on that topic on SO...?

Answer (score 0):

Using a .Net version of PHP ([Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php)) or using a .Net webservice to encode/decode isn't an option?

Comment: thanks mischa, but we are looking to cut costs. hence it is more elegant if we have a php equivalent of the hash function we used in c#.

anyway, thanks for leaving your answer. now i know there is such a thing as phalanger. which i previously didnt hear about.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<?php
 $key = "AE09F72B007CAAB5";
 echo base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", "test", $key, true));
?>
```

Comment: hi tt, nope didn't work. i got v1tgPrd6893541ZqrDVr4F1qHw8= instead of oK9NOVhpTkxLoLfvh1430SFb5gw=

Answer (score 0):

In C# the default formatting of the hash is in HEX (AE09F72B007CAAB5 is a hex number).PHP defaults to Base64 formatting. Solving your problem is a matter of converting the base64 string to hex in php

Comment: hi alex, thanks for answering. i wanted to ask you for more details, but i got the answer i needed. thank you.